# Question on intersection of ideals.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, monomial-ideals

> Consider the polynomial ring $k[x_0,x_1]$, and the two ideals $I=(x_0,x^2_0 x^2_1,x^3_1)$ and $J=(x^2_0,x^2_1)$. What is the intersection of these ideals?

I found that $I \cap J = (x^2_0,x^2_0x^2_1,x^3_1)$. Is this correct? In general, how can one compute the intersection of two ideals?

Answer (score 4):

you can compute the intersection of two ideals using the following. Introduce a new parameter, say 't'. Find the set $tI + (1-t)J$ and then compute a Groebner basis for this set. so you would have:
$$(tx_0,tx_1^2,tx_0^2,tx_1^3,(1-t)x_1^2,(1-t)x_0^2)$$
You can then compute a Groebner basis with respect to a lexicographic order with $t>x_0>x_1$ using Buchberger's Algorithm or autoreduction, whatever you feel more comfortable with. Finally remove all the terms from the Groebner Basis that contain a term with a t in. Then you will have your desired intersection.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I dont know anything about Groebner basis but I will look it up. For now, can you say if my computation is correct?

Comment: I agree with user26857's result below :)

Answer (score 4):

You actually have to intersect two *monomial* ideals, and this is well known; see e.g. [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150512110802/https://crazyproject.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/the-intersection-of-two-monomial-ideals-is-a-monomial-ideal/).

In your case we get $I\cap J=(x_0^2,x_0x_1^2,x_1^3)$.